# how to extract an element of JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I tried to extract the last line from a JTextArea and set it to a String
this is my cod:

```
JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
String text2 = text.getText();
int totalLines = text.getLineCount();
for(int j=0; j < totalLines; j++) {
   int end = text.getLineEndOffset(j);
   String line = text2.substring(end);
}
```

can someoane tell me where is the mistake? thanks

Comment: What is the output of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your really close, just use `JTextArea.getLineStartOffset` to get the start of the last line, example:

```
int last  = area.getLineCount() - 1;
int start = area.getLineStartOffset(last);
int end   = area.getLineEndOffset(last);

String lastLine = area.getText().substring(start, end);
```

Answer (score 2):

have look at [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) (model for [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)) and use [Text Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html) with methods

- [public static final int getRowStart(JTextComponent c, int offs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html#getRowStart%28javax.swing.text.JTextComponent,%20int%29)
- [public static final int getRowEnd(JTextComponent c, int offs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html#getRowEnd%28javax.swing.text.JTextComponent,%20int%29)

(`throws BadLocationException`)

EDIT

- [example by @Stas](http://java-sl.com/tip_row_column.html),
- [Retrieving the Visible Lines in a JTextComponent](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.text/GetWrappedLines.html)
- [Text Component Line Number by @ camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/text-component-line-number/)

EDIT 2

> how to extract an element of JTextArea

`element` could be `line` or `word` too